# .htaccess file for whole domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, server

I have this structure in my project:

```
domain.com

    -index.php

    frontend

        .htaccess

        -index.php
        -view1.php
        -view2.php

        account

            -index.php
            -view1.php
            -view2.php

    backend

        -class1.php
        -class2.php
```

domain.com/index.php:

```
include ( 'frontend/index.php' );
```

domain.com/frontend/index.php:

```
$str = $_GET['values'];
$str = str_replace ( '../' , '' , $str );

$file = $str . '.php';

if ( file_exists ( $file ) )
{
    include ( $file );
}
```

domain.com/frontend/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?values=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So which urls should be called to get specific templates(.php-files)?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think, that you realy want this :)
Try something like that

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?values=$1 [L]
```

Now u have $_GET[ 'values' ] = 'account/view1'
And you can handle it with PHP.

put your htaccess in your htdocs root, which is in your case your 'frontend' folder.
Your new index.php can be something like this

```
 <?php

      $str = $_GET[ 'values' ];
      $str = str_replace( '../', '', $str );

      $vars = explode( '/', $str );
      $path = '';
      foreach( $vars as $var ) {
           $p = strpos( $var, ':' );
           if( $p == 0  ) {
                $path .= $var . '/';
                continue;
           }
           $_GET[ sub_str( $var, 0, $p ) ] = sub_str( $var, $p + 1 );
      }

      if( $path ) {

           // File
           $file = $path . '.php';
           if( file_exists( $file ) ) {
                include( $file );
                exit;
           }

           // Direction
           $file = $path . '/index.php';
           if( file_exists( $file ) ) {
                include( $file );
                exit;
           }

           // Page not found // comment out if you dont want the default page
           // include( '404.php' );

      }

      // Default Page
      include( 'home.php' );
```

With this solution, you are allways in the same directory with php and you can interpret the URL as you want. You are able to include IDs in your URL or what ever you want and you can put in this file all your standard includes.

## Update

- Default page and Directory support
- Value Support. Example:

  ```
  http://domain.com/account/view/member_id:14

  = Result
  File: account/view/index.php
  $_GET[ 'member_id' ]: 14
  ```

Its not tested. Have fun :)

Comment: You mean, this should be the whole .htaccess ? And what about removing 'frontend' from the url?

Comment: You need a new index.php in the root which is a "gateway". Thats interpret your URL and open your files.

Comment: ok, so my '.htaccess' shoud be in 'frontend/.htaccess' and your code sould be in domain.de/index.php ?

Comment: your domain have to direct to 'frontend/' and both files (htaccess and index.php) have you to move in there.

Comment: you know what i mean?

Comment: and what i forgot: what is with the folder 'frontend' ?

Comment: yeah that are details now. That was only a basic. I can extend it for you :)

Comment: This would be great, could you give me an example for the structure i created? how to handle 'frontend' in url, index.php's etc ?? Thanks and Greetings!!